# .Net Controlling Screens from Server

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I know this is a typical request but still it is requirement for project. Basically we want to keep logic and design of screens on Server. And when client logins into the system that Screen gets downloaded and run on client machine. The best example of the same is SAP, where everything is being controlled at central location and user is able to create and customize screens.
I know web application like MVC or Click once deployment in Windows can be one of the solution but can we have any other solution then this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you described a web browser.

It's true that SAP use some kind of fancy ui design, but this is not by choice, but for historical reasons. SAP already has its own new (and fancy) web version of views and applications.

Today this kind of problem is solved using HTML5/javascript. You can do almost anything that you used to do on desktop (taking the UI perspective).

You can create your own fancy (and advanced) views definition (xml, json, tables on database, pick one), store that definitions as you want (database, files, etc.) and then generate the HTML/javascript/css for browser do the the work of display the content for the user. The browser will do the heavy lifting for you: download the files, parse, compile and run a client script language, cache resources, security, print, play sounds and videos...

The Browser is your thin client, with a huge amount of knowledge and effort applied to it,  result of almost 20 years of research. It is a proved application, tested everyday by dozens of thousands of people around the world. Your application will run on every single machine in this world that supports the open web technologies. You have the client already developed for you, for free. Why reinvent the wheel?

Even if you create your own particular way of run a rich web application from server (your view definition, your js generator...), you're not reinventing the wheel. Let's say that 1 year from now an amazing new feature appears and browser vendors implements it. Your application could benefit from that technology with a small (maybe big) change on HTML/js/css generator.

I can't see a single reason why one would create an entire new thin client and throw away all the open web technologies, especially now that ALL vendors are following the standards (IE10 is fine) and (hopefully) soon we'll no longer need hacks for each vendor.

Finally, if you don't want to use the browser you can still use the open web technologies. The awesomium project is a wrapper around the webkit engine that you can use in your winforms/wpf application but without the restrictions imposed by the general browsers. 
http://awesomium.com/